# Facebook Update Image API

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to update the image of a published post on my page through the node.js and when I am updating the message of the published post it is reflecting on my FB page but when I am trying to update the image it won't happen. I didn't understand where I am going wrong.

```
const {FB, FacebookApiException} = require('fb');


const access_token = "*********";
FB.setAccessToken(access_token);

FB.api(
  postId,
  'POST',
  { 
  message: 'A sample Post',
  url: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/417173/pexels-photo-417173.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
}, (res) => {
  if (!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`Post Id: `, res);
});
```

Comment: do you have an  error message, or a log?

Comment: instead of complicated constructs around console.log and `res`, better just do this instead and get all the info you need: `console.log(res);` and post the exact debug log.

Comment: I don’t see a parameter `url` defined anywhere when it comes to _creating_ a post, so why should that work for updating?

Comment: @misorude It is updating the message over the post

Comment: @SándorBakos There is no log coming It is updating the message over the post but not image

Comment: _“It is updating the message over the post”_ - yeah, so? `message` _is_ a valid parameter for post creation.

Comment: @misorude, I am asking if the message is updating why the image URL is not updating

Comment: And I am trying to tell you, that this is probably to be expected, when you make up arbitrary parameter names on your own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207975/discussion-between-axel-blaze-and-misorude).